# z-index does not work with transform:translate(-50%,-50%);

Tags: css

In `box1:after` `z-index:1;` it does not work.

```css
.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -3.5px;
  top: -3.5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Does anyone know what the solution is?

Comment: The class `.box1:after` creates an element inside `.box` not after it.

Comment: in .box:after (class) ... z-index:-1; is not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must to get help of `:before`, like this:

```css
.box1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 120px;
 height:120px;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.box1:before {
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 120px;
 content: 'click';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: gray;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.box1:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: -3.5px;
 top: -3.5px;
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
 border:4px solid red;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index:-1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Comment: but now text  <div class="box1">click</div> is not show in top.

Comment: where is `<div class="box">click</div>` in your code?

Comment: <div class="box1">click</div>